# How to get a String[] consisting of the .toString() calls of an ArrayList<Object> in one line

Tags: java, arrays, performance, arraylist

So i'm wondering if its possible to populate a String array made from toString() calls of an object ArrayList

So I know this can be done using a loop but is there a one line approach?

Loop approach

```
ArrayList<Object> objects = new ArrayList<Object>();
//fill object with elements 
//

String[] strings = new String[object.length()];
for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)strings[i]=objects.get(i).toString();
```

Answer (score 11):

Using java-8,

```
String[] strings = objects.stream().map(Object::toString).toArray(String[]::new);
```

Comment: Streams are awesome. I didn't know you could do stuff like `String[]::new`, thanks

Comment: Since the question has a “performance” tag, I feel I should point out that this is the right way to do it in one line, if that’s your goal, but it doesn’t buy you any performance gains over a simple for-loop.